# Deleting files on SD card does not free up space on SD card

Tags: sd-card

I'm facing this issue:

When I delete a big folder, it's not deleted, but moved in "system data" instead, I remove the card, I plug it in my pc and my pc says that the device has to be checked for errors, it runs the check and then creates a folder named found.000, if I delete this, the free space is regained! I've already formatted my SD card, same issue happened!

The strange thing is that this happens only with large/huge files and folders, if I delete some megabytes, not a byte is added in system data! so I think I need to think why could this be happening with large data

I've got a similar 1 gb of data in internal too but this should be the mi cloud backup?
is it stored locally?
how can I delete it?
(I'm root)

Comment: device is redmi note 5a, but you didn't understand, pc says device has to be checked when I connect the sd card to the pc using a card reader, I tried deletions both with es file explorer pro, solid explorer and rom's default explorer, best result I got is big files get deleted after reboot, till then they are moved to system data

Comment: Before removing the sdcard from the phone and your pc you need to eject/unmount it otherwise file-system errors may occur.

Comment: errors occur (lost chains) because of the inability to actually delete the big files and not from removing the sd card I think

Comment: Deleting a file works interdependent of it's size. Only if the app you use for deleting tries to emulator some sort of trash where the files are copied to it can make problems -> use a program that does not use such a strange implementation of the delete command.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using ES File Explorer, when you 'delete' from the SD Card the data doesn't delete, it gets moved into a folder called .estrongs (you have put the sd card into PC and in Windows File Explorer under View Tab check the box for 'show hidden files')...checking the box for showing 'hidden files' in ES Explorer is not reliable.....Then in just delete the files from .estrongs in Windows File Explorer to free up space

Answer (score 0):

Connect your SD card to PC/laptop and perform a `chkdsk` repair

Comment: I did that twice and lately I formatted my sd card from inside the phone, another strange thing is that no matter how I format it, the phone detects it with a serial number, like C42B-1819, any way I can make phone detect it as sd card1 or something?

Comment: I noticed the same thing happens when I delete a large file from the internal storage,
is this a nougat feature or a miui one?
any way I can force android to delete these files instantly instead of moving them to system data 
and maybe deleting after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I think a **Cold Restart** (*Turning the device completely off and then back on.*) Should fix this issue.

In some rare cases you may need to remove the card when the device is off and put it back before restarting.

Then when you start back up you should see your actual available space on the SD card/Micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @river 's answer - on Mac OS, you can press 'Shift' + 'Command' + '.' on the keyboard to enable hidden files view, and from there you can check the SD card to determine if there's a hidden folder or trash folder where the deleted files gets moved to. In my case for a SANDISK Extreme pro it was moved to a hidden Trash folder. HTH.